# Compiling f# for xbox360

Tags: f#, xna-4.0

I've been trying to compile some libraries I've written in f# to work in a game I'm writing for the xbox360, except I keep getting an error saying `"The module/namespace 'System.Net.WebRequest' from compilation unit 'System' did not contain the namespace, module or type 'WebRequest'`.

The command I've been using to compile it is

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft F#\v4.0\fsc.exe" -o:obj\Release\XBox360.dll --standalone --noframework --define:TRACE --optimize+ --tailcalls+ -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XNA\XNA Game Studio\v4.0\References\Xbox360\mscorlib.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XNA\XNA Game Studio\v4.0\References\Xbox360\System.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\2.0\Runtime\v2.0\FSharp.Core.dll" --target:library --warn:3 --warnaserror:76 --fullpaths --flaterrors somefile.fs
```

Does anyone know of a way to fix, or avoid this problem?

Answer (score 9):

The xbox [xna](/questions/tagged/xna) assemblies are a cut down version of the normal .net ones (it uses the client framework +- a few bits).

One major limitation is that with xna on the xbox you can only communicate using microsoft's LIVE servers. i.e. no web requests.

You can see this by comparing the [`SerializableAttribute` page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx), which is supported (has the xna symbol next to supported members and constructors) with the [`WebRequest` page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx), which does not.

---

**All is not lost**. It appears the core F# DLLS require that class to be present in System, so you can't just link to the XNA/xbox versions of the core library.
Luckely some people at microsoft kindly built DLLs without this restriction. See here:

https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1teGhBf-m7qRkMzsbCKvRcIEo-QLwdK9w8VOEWqu1qWQ/edit#slide=id.ge02f430_0_70 Slide 29.

> XNA + F# on Xbox 360 is not an officially supported combination. Lack
>   of support for tail calls in CLR causes crashes with the standard F#
>   core lib. Don Syme and others at Microsoft kindly provided a custom
>   made F# core lib for the Xbox 360. Need to fiddle with the .fsproj
>   files (can be done automatically using a script).

In that presentation I found the following links:

**Project containing F# DLLs especially built for XNA** (Looks like the folder FSharpCore in [Source](https://bitbucket.org/johdex/xnautils/src) is what you're after): https://bitbucket.org/johdex/xnautils

A blog about developing for XNA in F#: http://sharp-gamedev.blogspot.co.uk/

Comment: Is there a way to get around this? (I'm using VS 2012 and played around with the project MSBuild files until I got this; see my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993514/target-the-xna-framework-in-ordinary-visual-studio-2012-project))

Comment: Unfortunately not. Even if you could some how get it to compile (by creating your own version of the DLLs or something) MS specifically don't let you communicate with anything other than a media server (for streaming music etc) or their LIVE service.

Comment: Why doesn't it work if you disable the WebRequest stuff though, so the only method to communicate with other computers _would_ be what you mentioned?

Comment: I've looked at your comment in the question you linked above, but honestly I'm now out of my depth. I would imagine F# needs the dll with `WebRequest`, but if you say it doesn't work if you use the version with `WebRequest` (without using it in code) then it's probably to do with the way the XNA framework/pipeline is set up. My guess is it's not going to work. However **all is not lost** (see my edit)

Comment: Just noticed this in the [Open source F# README.md on Github](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/README.md): "You can also build FSharp.Core for ... XNA 4.0 for Xbox 360 profiles: ... msbuild fsharp-library-build.proj /p:TargetFramework=net40-xna40-xbox360 /p:Configuration=Release"