# Target the XNA framework in ordinary Visual Studio 2012 project

Tags: visual-studio, f#, xna, visual-studio-2012, xna-4.0

I have a C# XNA host project, with an F# client project that will contain all my functionality. It won't build because the F# project has references to mscorlib.dll and System.dll that the XNA project doesn't agree with (the actual error -- well, its really a warning that in my opinion *should* be an error -- is at the bottom of the post). How can I tell the F# project to target the actual XNA platform (specifically for the Xbox 360)?

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1578,5): warning MSB3268: The primary reference "\\vmware-host\Shared Folders\Projects\FSharp\Whirlygigs\Whirlygigs.Lib\bin\Debug\Whirlygigs.Lib.dll" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "\\vmware-host\Shared Folders\Projects\FSharp\Whirlygigs\Whirlygigs.Lib\bin\Debug\Whirlygigs.Lib.dll" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=***".
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1578,5): warning MSB3268: The primary reference "\\vmware-host\Shared Folders\Projects\FSharp\Whirlygigs\Whirlygigs.Lib\bin\Debug\Whirlygigs.Lib.dll" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "\\vmware-host\Shared Folders\Projects\FSharp\Whirlygigs\Whirlygigs.Lib\bin\Debug\Whirlygigs.Lib.dll" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=***".
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the version of .Net you are targeting - I think it should be 3.5 instead of 4

Comment: Have you tried targeting `.NET Framework 4` instead of `.NET Framework 4 Client Profile`? (On the `Application` tab of project properties)

Comment: I just tried all the listed .NET frameworks (2.0, 3.0, 3.0 Client Profile, 4, 4.0 Client Profile, and 4.5), but all of them produce the exact same warnings. I'm not sure what to make of this...

Answer (score 4):

The problem that you are having is that one of your projects is targeting the Windows versions of the .NET Framework (`mscorlib`, `System`) and one of your projects is targeting the Xbox 360 versions of the framework. And, basically, you cannot link together assemblies targeting different core frameworks.

I'm guessing that your F# project is targeting the Windows versions of the assemblies. **What you need to do is get your F# project to target the Xbox 360 reference assemblies.**

(Note that I've never done this myself - so my answer is just a list of things you could try.)

For your reference, these reference assemblies are installed by default to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XNA\XNA Game Studio\v4.0\References\Xbox360\`

First of all, you could try using the Portable Class Library. I've heard mixed reports about this.

The way I would probably do this is with some manual MSBuild trickery. A Visual Studio project file *is* an MSBuild file (which is XML). You can open it up in a text editor and play with it. You'll notice that an XNA project imports the following file:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\XNA Game Studio\Microsoft.Xna.GameStudio.targets" />
```

So you could try simply adding that import to your project file (and maybe some of the other XNA configuration, like `<XnaPlatform>`, in the appropriate place). That *might* do the trick.

If not, you could actually look at these files (they're at `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\XNA Game Studio\v4.0`) and try and figure out what they're using to set the path for framework assemblies. I'm not knowledgeable enough with MSBuild to say for sure.

Otherwise, **you could just brute-force it**. You can turn off the built-in referencing of the core frameworks by adding this to a `<PropertyGroup>`:

```
<NoStdLib>true</NoStdLib>
```

And then manually set the paths for each reference. So you would change this:

```
<Reference Include="mscorlib" />
```

To this:

```
<Reference Include="mscorlib">
  <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XNA\XNA Game Studio\v4.0\References\Xbox360\mscorlib.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

And so on for all the other references. I've previously had success with this last method, for doing something similar (manually changing the target framework).

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the answer; but I won't be able to test this for another week or two as my VMWare trial expired literally the day after you responded, and I can't buy it for a bit. Also sorry for the late answer, but thanks again! :)

Comment: I know, this is reaaaaaally late, but anyway -- I've gotten really close simply by adding any properties having to do with XNA that I found in a C# XNA project, and it actually worked! It appears to be targeting the XNA compact framework, so I added all the references in VS 2012, but it looks like F# needs one of the complete framework classes -- WebRequest in System.Net. Here's the error: `The module/namespace 'System.Net' from compilation unit System did not include the namespace, module or type 'WebRequest'`. Any ideas?

Comment: BTW: I didn't brute-force it, I used your second approach, plus some.

Comment: Hmm, I found [a topic about this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8256689/compiling-f-for-xbox360), by someone who had the same problem...